# Create view like details of apple app store

Tags: ios

I am looking to create a control like apple shows on app store under details expanded view. It looks like UIPageViewController with UIPageControl but i am unable to achieve a part of left and right view on either side of selected screen. Or is it UICollectionView inside UIScrollView with UIPageControl?

[image]

Comment: it is just simple scrollview with pagingEnabled=true

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Also we use [this library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) in our project.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to achieve it using paging enabled, now going to check out other libraries as well.